# Disposition of "under specified" questions where OP isn't participating

Tags: discussion

We seem to have a fair number of "drive by" questions where the OP has asked a question that is too broad to answer without further input, but where the OP isn't responding to comments. On some of these the comments have some good information and seem worth keeping open, but others seem to me to just dilute the quality of the site.

So, I'm wondering if it would make sense to prune some of these away? I'm thinking that questions that bring up good discussion (even in the comments) would be worth keeping – especially if we could find a way to encourage people to "reactivate" them. Is there a way for a new user to say "I'm having the problem too" other than as an answer that should get flagged?

Comment: I have seen comments that in themselves may have provided the answer indirectly